# Force a router to keep a an IDLE UDP port open

Tags: udp, router, nat, hole-punching

A client opens a UDP connection to my server , after some time (10 minutes-24 hours) the server needs to send data back to the client but it finds that the UDP port of the client is closed !.

After testing , we found that the client still have the UDP port open , but the router (nat) closed the port probably for inactivity !

is there any way to force the router to keep the UDP port open without sending keep-alive packets ? (server or client side) .

is there anything like that in ICMP ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I find this solution, not for the router, but for the server:

Try to configure the keep alive.

The way to do it depends of which service / program / OS are you using.

For example, using OpenSSH in the Client, you had to add/configure this lines in the file `./ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 60
```

In the server (where I made the change) add/configure this lines in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 60
```

Of course it depends of the operative system, etc. but the idea is to configurate the keep alive right in the service.

Good luck!

Comment: the problem is the service is always open on a UDP port and not TCP , so when no data is being sent through an open port on the ROUTER , the router will assume te UDP connection is lost and close the port .